A problem about zero-measure set in manifold.
Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold. A subset $N \subset M$ is said to have zero measure if the sets $\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(N) \subset U_\alpha$ have zero measure for every parameterization $\varphi_\alpha: U_\alpha \rightarrow M$ in the maximal atlas.
(a) Prove that in order to show that $N \subset M$ has zero measure it suffices to check that the sets $\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(N) \subset U_\alpha$ have zero measure for the parameterizations in an arbitrary atlas.
(b) Suppose that $M$ is oriented. Let $\omega \in \Omega^n(M)$ be compactly supported and let $W=\varphi(U)$ be a coordinate neighborhood such that $M \backslash W$ has zero measure. Show that
$$
\int_M \omega=\int_U \varphi^* \omega,
$$
The question is from <An Introduction to Riemannian Geometry：With Applications to Mechanics and Relativity> section 2.4
My idea: (1) is trivial. To solve (2),
Step 1:
Choose an oriented atlas contains (W,$\varphi$) namely (W,$W_1$,$\dots$,$W_n$)(I don't know how to show the existence).
Step 2:
We need to choose a family of smooth partition functions dominated to the oriented atlas given in Step 1. For the one who supported on $W$(denoted by $\rho$), its support set must sufficiently approximate W and its value take 1 as much as possible. Then probably, the value of remain terms $\sum_{i=1}^n\int_M\rho_i w$ will be very small.
$$
 \int_{M}\omega=\int_W\rho w+\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{W_i}\rho_i w
$$
Step 3:
Since integration on manifold is independent of the choice of partition of union and oriented atlas, if we can sufficiently approximate the value on left hand side by using Step 2, we can obtain:
$$
|\int_M \omega-\int_U \varphi^* \omega|<\varepsilon
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. Then we complete the proof.
This is just a vague idea and there are lots of details need to be complemented.

What have you tried about this?

$ \phi_{\beta} \circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1} $ is differentiable, so it maps sets of zero measure to sets of zero measure. Using this, (a) is easy to check.

I'm still working on it. If I come up with some ideas, I will update it on this page.

I think we just need some manipulation of definitions.
Let $\{W_i = \varphi_i(U_i)\}$ be a finite open cover of $supp\  \omega$ by domains of positively oriented smooth charts. And let $\{\psi_i\}$ be a smooth partition of unity with respect to this cover. By definition, $$
\int_M\omega = \Sigma_i\int_{U_i}\varphi_i^*(\psi_i\omega) = \Sigma_i\int_{\varphi_i^{-1}(W\cap W_i)}\varphi_i^*(\psi_i\omega) \\=  \Sigma_i\int_{\varphi^{-1}(W\cap W_i)}\varphi^*(\psi_i\omega) = 
\Sigma_i\int_{\varphi^{-1}(W)}\varphi^*(\psi_i\omega) = \int_{\varphi^{-1}(W)}\varphi^*(\Sigma_i \psi_i\omega) = \int_{U}\varphi^*\omega
$$

The second equality is because $\varphi^{-1}_i(M\backslash W \cap W_i)$ is of zero measure and the forth equality is because $Supp\  \psi_i \subset W_i$.
